# 'QBChatRoom' is deprecated: Use QBChatDialog instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I'm following the [QuickBlox WebRTC tutorial for iOS](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios) and as soon as I add #import statements in Step 4 and try to build I get the following compiler error:

```
/path/to/project/Quickblox.framework/Headers/QBChatDialog.h:167:33: 'QBChatRoom' is deprecated: Use QBChatDialog instead
```

Have I missed a step or done something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Lenny

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning,

I guess you should set a key
GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS to false in your Xcode settings to compile with warnings